# Error while launching "hive" command in shell

Tags: php, hive, thrift, cosmos, fiware-cosmos

When I try to run the "hive" command from the shell I get the following error:

> 'Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to
>   create /tmp/hadoop-USERNAME/hadoop-unjar1448268252380539144 at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.ensureDirectory(RunJar.java:100) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:162)'.

But when I try and select query in PHP script, we received the following error:

> 'FAILED: Hive Internal Error:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot
>   create directory
>   /tmp/hive-root/hive_2015-06-29_18-03-29_493_5508174623301334280. Name
>   node is in safe mode. Resources are low on NN. Safe mode must be
>   turned off manually. at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2140)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:2114)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.mkdirs(NameNode.java:892)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2286.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:557)'

Comment: is there enough disk space on given node?

Answer (score 0):

This was due the cluster automatically entered in safe mode. We fixed it by freeing/adding some disk space.

Answer (score 0):

the "df -h" commands shows:

tmpfs 4,9G 0 4,9G 0% /dev/shm

The partition is free.
The problem, unexpecedly, is gone even if I have not erased any data.
There are another problem on hive instance. When I try to launch a select query on some fields the hive cli map reduced returns this error:

Ended Job = job_201409031055_6624 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Examining task ID: task_201409031055_6624_m_000002 (and more) from job job_201409031055_6624

Task with the most failures(4):

Task ID:
task_201409031055_6624_m_000000

URL:

http://cosmosmaster-gi:50030/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201409031055_6624&tipid=task_201409031055_6624_m_000000

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Job 0: Map: 1 HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec